# Different Keras Augmentation on Training and Validation

Tags: python, keras

I am running augmentation for image classification purposes - using Keras - as:

```
# Define Parameters
parameters = {"img_width" : 224,
              "img_height": 224,
              "epochs": 50,
              "batch_size" : 15}

# Define Generators  
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. / 255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    validation_split = 0.06)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1/255)

# Define Flows from directories
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory = train_data_dir,
    target_size=(parameters["img_width"], parameters["img_height"]),
    batch_size = parameters["batch_size"],
    class_mode= "categorical", 
    subset = "training", 
    color_mode = "rgb",
    seed = 42)

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory = train_data_dir,
    target_size = (parameters["img_width"], parameters["img_height"]),
    batch_size = parameters["batch_size"],
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset = "validation",
    color_mode = "rgb",
    seed = 42)

testing_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe = testing_df, 
        x_col="path", y_col="label", 
        class_mode="raw", 
        target_size= (parameters["img_width"], parameters["img_height"]), 
        shuffle = False,
        batch_size= parameters["batch_size"])
```

and this code produces as output for training, validation and testing: Found 4911 images belonging to 69 classes.
Found 282 images belonging to 69 classes.
Found 421 validated image filenames.

However, if I would like to use test_datagen, instead of train_datagen, for validation data as:

```
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    # Changing Line        
    directory = train_data_dir,
    target_size = (parameters["img_width"], parameters["img_height"]),
    batch_size = parameters["batch_size"],
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset = "validation",
    color_mode = "rgb",
    seed = 42)
```

I get the output: Found 0 images belonging to 69 classes.

How can I solve this issue? Briefly, I would like to validate the data on images the model will be effectively run on, hence using test_datagen that only scales values.

P.s. train_data_dir is a folder that contains 69 folders with images from different classes;

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be referencing the same directory for the validation and training.

Try pointing to a specific validation directory like:

```
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    # Changing Line        
    directory = validation_data_dir,
    target_size = (parameters["img_width"], parameters["img_height"]),
    batch_size = parameters["batch_size"],
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset = "validation",
    color_mode = "rgb",
    seed = 42)
```

The directories should be something like:

```
train/
    69 folders
validation/
    69 folders
test/ 
    69 folders
```

For instance the setup I generally use is:

```
train_data_dir = (str(cwd) + r'\augmented\train\\')
validation_data_dir = (str(cwd) + r'\augmented\validation\\')

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
```

To augment images into separate directories you could do something like the following, mind you it will be a little tedious and I recommend creating a loop from a list of your classes. For my example I was only doing a binary classification, 1 or 0. I took an "original" 0 image and augmented across the train, validation, and test folders, then ran the script again for the 1 image. You have a lot more classes hence the suggestion to loop a list.

```
# rescaling is disabled to allow the images to be viewed
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')

# this is a PIL image # path + filename
img = load_img(r'path_to_single_image_to_be_augmented')
# this is a Numpy array with shape (3, 150, 150)
x = img_to_array(img)
# this is a Numpy array with shape (1, 3, 150, 150)
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)

# the .flow() command below generates batches of randomly transformed
# images and saves the results to save_to_dir - remember to change prefix
i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=1,
                          save_to_dir=(str(cwd) + r'\augmented\test\0'),
                          save_prefix='0', save_format='jpeg'):
    i += 1
    if i > 110:  # change the amount of augmented data you want here
        break  # otherwise the generator would loop indefinitely

i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=1,
                          save_to_dir=(str(cwd) + r'\augmented\test\0'),
                          save_prefix='0', save_format='jpeg'):
    i += 1
    if i > 280:  
        break  

i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=1,
                          save_to_dir=(str(cwd) + r'\augmented\validation\0'),
                          save_prefix='0', save_format='jpeg'):
    i += 1
    if i > 280: 
        break
```

Comment: What I found is that even if I change directory, but keep the "subset = validation/training", then it returns 0 images for validation. Do you confirm this finding? @55thSwiss

Comment: Yes, that would make sense. If you're using `validation_split` you shouldn't have multiple directories. If you're not using it (as in my code) then you use separate directories

Comment: is there a way to automatically generate a validation folder with the number of classes? I only have a single folder with the classes' folder.

Comment: I edited my response to show how I augmented my images. Create a loop as I suggested because you have many more classes